# STM32 IRQ Firing Too Early

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I am using an STM32L010 micro to receive some data via the UART. Specifically, I am looking to receive six bytes and can block until I get it. For this reason, I am using the HAL_UART_Receive_IT function that is part of the STM32 HAL Driver library:

```
while(1)
{
    if ( Data_Ready == FALSE )
    {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_Data, 6);
    }
    else if ( Data_Ready == TRUE )
    {
    //Do some data processing
        Data_Ready = FALSE;       //Clear flag
    }
}
```

I have a flag in the UART IRQ handler that should get set when all six bytes are transferred.

```
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
  Data_Ready = TRUE;
}
```

However, the IRQ is firing when I have only one byte in RX_Data. I have verified with a scope that the data is NOT just one byte and then all zeroes.

Am I misunderstanding how this handler works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interrupts are purely hardware, they have nothing to do with the HAL. Firing every byte is normal if the hardware is configured that way. What you want is the HAL callback, namely `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`. This one will be called once the requested transfer is completed. The HAL takes care of processing the interrupts, possibly every byte, and abstracts them into your HAL requests.

Comment: Isn't the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback defined as __weak inside the hal libraries so all you have to do is redefine it?

Comment: @RichardBamford Yes that's right. The user should implement their own `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`, which will be called by the HAL.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, in the absence of any characters being received, can be distilled to this:

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_Data, 6);
}
```

This is not how to use the interrupt driven receive routine. You can't just call that function in a tight loop. If you were checking the return value from `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` (which you absolutely should be), you'd see it is returning `HAL_BUSY` every time you call it (except the first).

If you had to use interrupts, you should call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()`, then wait until all the bytes have been received before calling it again. You can use `HAL_UART_GetState()` to see if the UART is still busy, or has received everything.

Note that using the interrupt-driven receive routine, then polling for its completion, is completely pointless. The reason why the interrupt-driven (and also DMA) functions exist is so that the CPU can do *something else* while the reception takes place. You'd be as well to just use the polling `HAL_UART_Receive()` if you have nothing else to do.

As @ElderBug pointed out, you will get an interrupt for every character when receiving in interrupt mode, and you need to use the receive complete callback instead of the bare ISR. But I suspect you should not be using interrupts here.

A more sane solution (for the requirements you described):

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

    status = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, RX_Data, 6, 1000); // 1 second timeout

    if (status == HAL_OK)
    {
        // Yay, got 6 bytes, process them.
    }
    else
    {
        // Boo, timeout or error, handle that
    }
}
```

Note that no interrupts are involved, and you can remove any changes to ISRs you have made, and also just completely disable interrupts on the UART.

Comment: I thought I *was* waiting for all the bytes to be received by setting the flag in the IRQ. I understand now that gets called on every byte transfer.

Comment: Interrupts are completely pointless if "I am looking to receive six bytes and can block until I get it". You're making your life harder for no reason. The polling receive routine does exactly what you want, i.e. blocks until you get it (or time out).

Comment: Even if you use the receive complete callback from the HAL (to set a flag), your code has a race condition between the main loop detecting the flag is set, and you starting a new reception (into the same buffer you're about to process). You should reconsider your approach, or you will be haunted by mysterious bugs later on.